# Can an isomorphism between two finite-dimensional linear spaces be always represented by a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Is that true? Any counter-example?

Comment: any linear transformation, isomorphism or not, can be represented by a matrix (which is finite if the dimensions are finite).

Comment: An isomorphism is simply an invertible linear map from one vector space to another, and hence, can be represented by a matrix.